# Comparar fechas en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

tengo dos campos que ingresan como atributos a un stored procedure para que me arroje los datos ambos son de tipo DATE:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="desde" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="hasta" CssClass="form-control" TextMode="Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

lo que necesito es que si el segundo campo HASTA si no se seleccione o quede en blanco, que sea igual al dato seleccionado en DESDE

la condicion supongo que se podra realizar en C#

ayudenme porfavor, solo necesito la condicion lo demas ya lo tengo

Comment: Si tienes un `<asp:Button OnClick="" />` o algo parecido, donde haces el `PostBack` hacia el Servidor, podrías indicarlo en el código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el evento `OnClick` del botón o control que envía tu página .aspx al servidor, debes realizar la comparación de las fechas.

Supón que el código de tu **botón** es el siguiente:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Id_Enviar" OnClick="Id_Enviar_Click" Text="Enviar" />
```

En el **Code Behind** de tu página (C#), define el evento `OnClick` de la siguiente manera:

```
    protected void Id_Enviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var _desdeText = desde.Text;
        var _hastaText = hasta.Text;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_hastaText))
        {
            _hastaText = _desdeText;
        }

        try
        {
            DateTime _desdeFecha = DateTime.Parse(_desdeText);
            DateTime _hastaFehca = DateTime.Parse(_hastaText);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }            
    }
```